# Flutter- how to set image path for imagePicker in any folder?

Tags: dart, flutter

This is saving image inside android path somewhere like this'/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/, but I want to save in my folder.

```
File _image;
Future getImage() async {
  var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
  setState(() {
    _image = image;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use the `ImageSource.gallery` if you want to choose(in the gallery) where you want to save the image

Comment: How does `ImageSource.gallery` allow customization?

Comment: i think he want to open the gallery folder because he didn't mention  where is his  "folder"

Comment: Thanks, but I want to save the image after clicking from camera to my location.
Image is saving here '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/sutara.org.maui/files/Pictures/02ea5fc7-1013-4364-8916-1d56782b2d261362500779.jpg' but I want t.o save it in my custom location

Comment: where is your location ?